# SP 2013 Calendar - Change View: Day, Week, Month on the fly

Tags: 2013, calendar, view

So what I'd like to achieve is something like the image below

[image]

which enables our users to change the view of the home page calendar on the fly.

I've attached this mock up gif of what I want to achieve, I have done a fair bit of searching, but can only find options to set the default to one particular view, however i've yet to find any info for letting the user decide on the fly what view they'd like to see.

Any ideas?

Comment: The buttons exist in the ribbon area already, do those buttons do what you want? However you want the buttons moved down to above the calendar itself?

Comment: Hi David, yeah I had noticed the area within the ribbon that allows for the change in view on the calendar. You are correct, I'd like to have the functionality on the calendar itself as opposed to within the ribbon.